# how access to array in another scope in same function java script?

Tags: javascript

I have a function to add some item to array and check in another scope if this array has data:

```js
function addtolist() {
  if (listData.lenght == 0) {
    var arrry = new Array();
    array.push(text.value);
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i] == text.value) {
        return false;
      } else {
        array.puch(text.value);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In first case, when list is empty, code runs correctly. But in else condition in for statement see array length == 0. how can i fix this

any idea?!

Comment: You have typos: `if (listData.lenght == 0)`, `array.puch(text.value);`. Also, `array` is local, and this function returns undefined, so this function has no effect.

Comment: how can i make array seen in else scope? to check and add if data not exist

Comment: Fix this typo, also: `var arrry =`. Also, move its declaration just after the `function addtolist()`. But unless you give `array` global scope, the function will still have no effect.

Comment: @terrymorse it`s working correctly thanks

Answer (score 0):

OP is confusing so going by the intent of what the OP's code looks like it's doing is that OP wants an array of unique values. OP does not provide the definition of `text.value`... is it an object?:

```
let text = {
  value: 'X'
};

// text.value = 'X';
```

Is it a string from an `<input>`?

```
// <input id='text' value='X'>

let text = document.getElementById('text');

// text.value = 'X';
```

So this demo covers both scenarios. In order to have an array of unique values (ie an array with no duplicates):

- Add the new string to array (don't worry if array is empty or if new string is already in array)
- Convert array into a Set (Set will not keep duplicate values)
- Convert Set back to an array

---

## Demo

```js
let list = [];

//~~~~~~ If text.value from <input>

document.getElementById('text').onchange = addFromInput;


function addFromInput(event) {
  let string = event.target.value;
  list.push(string);
  let set = new Set(list);
  console.log(`addFromInput() returns: ${[...set]}`);
}

//~~~~~~if text.value from Object

let text = {
  value: 'X'
};

let string = text.value;

function addFromObject(string, array) {
  array.push(string);
  let set = new Set(array);
  return [...set];
}

console.log(`addFromObject() returns: ${addFromObject(string, list)}`);
```

```html
<input id='text'><button>GO!</button>
```